# Transform a list of numbers into a specific price format with a suffix in PHP or JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a huge list like the below. Using PHP or JavaScript, how can I convert that list to `15.810 EUR` ?

```
15810
18620
13990
19250
2950
26950
9498
9498
9930
14990
13850
19850
16850
9850
10850
10850
7450
15450
8850
7950
21850
7350
```

Comment: From where do you know where to set the comma/ dot? Could also be: `158.10 EUR`?

Comment: Easily, but why do you have three decimal numbers for a currency? Will there *always* be three decimal numbers? And, out of curiosity, did you make any attempt at solving this yourself? Where are the numbers found, in the site itself (in the HTML) or in an array, or an object, or a string..? Will the currency always be Euro, or does it vary?

Comment: Divide each by 1000...

Comment: price.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

Comment: @DavidThomas yes there will be always 3 demical and this is the "normal" way into my country...

Comment: http://numeraljs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PHP this should work for you:

```
<?php

    $numbers = array(15810, 18620, 13990, 19250, 2950, 26950, 9498, 9498, 9930, 14990, 13850, 19850, 16850, 9850, 10850, 10850, 7450, 15450, 8850, 7950, 21850, 7350);

    foreach($numbers as $key => $value) {
        $numbers[$key] = number_format($value/1000, 3) . " EUR";
        echo $numbers[$key] . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
15.810 EUR
18.620 EUR
13.990 EUR
19.250 EUR
//...
```

**EDIT:**

If you're numbers aren't stored in a array you can just explode it:

```
<?php

    $numbers = "15810
                18620
                13990
                19250
                //...
                7950
                21850
                7350";

    $numbers = explode("\n", trim($numbers));

    foreach($numbers as $key => $value) {
        $numbers[$key] = number_format($value/1000, 3) . " EUR";
        echo $numbers[$key] . "<br />";
    } 

?>
```

Or if your list is separated with spaces you can do this:

```
<?php 

    $numbers = "15810 18620 13990 19250 2950 26950 9498 9498 9930 14990 13850 19850 16850 9850 10850 10850 7450 15450 8850 7950 21850 7350";

    $numbers = explode(" ", $numbers);

    foreach($numbers as $key => $value) {
        $numbers[$key] = number_format($value/1000, 3) . " EUR";
        echo $numbers[$key] . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

Comment: What if I can't put them like `15810, 18620, 13990, 19250, 2950,` ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: I have the list like I posted in the question, not with commas

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos How is your list seperated? With space?

Comment: You're a lot better in arrays than me ;)